# Quaternion Exponential map

Tags: lie-algebras, quaternions, tangent-spaces

I am trying to figure out how excatly the exponential/log map with quaternion works. I was reading this:
http://alumni.media.mit.edu/~aries/papers/johnson_phd.pdf

Half way at page 70 it says: "Computationally, the most robust way..." but I don't really understand 2 things:
1- how does he get to that equation?
2- how does it prove that the logarithm map is linear?

I read somewhere else a proof for complex number that showed how log map is linear by deriving the exp and log functions and then the log derivative was a constant and therefore not curved. I think I would like to find an analogous proof for quaternions, can anyone help with it?

Cheers,

Comment: Do you mean that the logarithm of the exponential is linear? Do you understand how to compute $e^q$ for a quaternion $q$?

Comment: no what I meant is that the logarithm maps to a linear vector space (for my understanding of the topic) but I don't find a way to prove it in the same way as for the complex number. I asked a more specific question here:https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3292181/quaternion-differentiation-following-complex-number-example 
in this question is more about asking what that algorithm is, while in the other question is more about how to derive a quaternion.

Comment: as for the other question, I read about it a lot in the last couple of days, but I didn't understand it super clearly.